# Group by substring and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query

```
select U_YBID, T1.onhand
from oitw T1
inner join oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode=T2.ItemCode
where T1.WhsCode='01' and U_YBID is not null and u_YBId like '%/%'
```

It gives output like this:

```
302/02  41.000000
302/01  23.000000
X82/02  20.000000
355/01  2.000000
355/02  4.000000
355/03  5.000000
```

I need query which gives  the `sum` and id for eg:

```
302    64
x82    20
355    11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `left`:

```
select left(U_YBID, 3)
     , sum(T1.onhand)
from oitw T1
inner join oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
where T1.WhsCode = '01' and u_YBId like '%/%
group by left(U_YBID, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If length of string in column `U_YBID` before `/` is not static to `3` then you can write a query as:

```
SELECT U_YBID,SUM (T1.onhand) AS T1.onhand
FROM 
( 
select PARSENAME(REPLACE(U_YBID, '/', '.'), 2) AS U_YBID , T1.onhand
from oitw T1
inner join oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode=T2.ItemCode
where T1.WhsCode='01' and U_YBID is not null and u_YBId like '%/%'
)AS T
GROUP BY U_YBID
```

You can read more about `PARSENAME` function [here..](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `substring` and `group by`

```
select substring(U_YBID,1,3), sum(T1.onhand)
from oitw T1
inner join oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode=T2.ItemCode
where T1.WhsCode='01' and U_YBID is not null and u_YBId like '%/%
group by substring(U_YBID,1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use mid function
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_mid

```
SELECT MID(U_YBID,1,3), 
       SUM(T1.onhand)
       FROM oitw T1
       INNER JOIN oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode=T2.ItemCode
       WHERE T1.WhsCode='01' and U_YBID is not null and u_YBId like '%/%
       GROUP MID(U_YBID,1,3);
```